# How to redirect to subdomain in .htaccess file with multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an .htaccess file that sends example1.com, example2.com, and example3.com to different files on my server

I want to make it so example3.com temporarily redirects to a subdomain that has been given its own A record: forums.example3.com.  Would like to do it in .htaccess instead of DNS settings.  It should show forums.example3.com in the URL bar too.  I want to also make it so I can remove the redirect in the future without too much re-coding.  So far i cant even figure out the redirect as every attempt at rewriting this working code for the redirect always fails:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+.)example.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+.)example2.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example2.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+.)example3.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example3.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://example3.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    #othersites in othersites folder
    RewriteCond $1 !^othersites/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.)$ /othersites/example2.com/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond $1 !^othersites/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example3.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.)$ /othersites/example3.com/$1 [L]
```

what code should I add/change to redirect example3.com to forums.example3.com? Preferably in the most SEO friendly way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this rule is most likely wrong: `RewriteRule ^(.)$`

One single dot represents one single character, whereas you usually want to allow zero or more.

What you want instead should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$`

The exclamation mark specifies a negative match. So if the host being requested is example3.com, then this rule will be met:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$`

But the previous one would fail anyway:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+.)example.com [NC]`

However I would write more explicit rules and avoid negative matches if unnecessary, as they can easily lead to unwanted results.

So, the following rule should be enough to redirect example3.com (with or without subdomain) to http://forums.example3.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+\.)?example3.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://forums.example3.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Since you are saying you want to set up a temporary redirect, you may instead use HTTP code 302 for the redirect.

Comment: thanks, now how do I tell it to use the files in /othersites/example3.com/forums as well as update the URL to forums.example3.com?

appending 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forums\.example3\.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /addons/example3\.com/forums/$1 

Doesnt seem to keep forums.example3.com to keep from pulling files from my main html folder, which is example1.com

Comment: Something like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/othersites/example3.com/forums$` and you could also use [OR] to regroup your rules, see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html